# Consecutive Numbers in SQL (Leetcode)

Tags: mysql

The question is for Table: Logs

```
+-------------+---------+
| Column Name | Type    |
+-------------+---------+
| id          | int     |
| num         | varchar |
+-------------+---------+
```

id is the primary key for this table. Write an SQL query to find all numbers that appear at least three times consecutively.

My solution is the following, which Leetcode is not accepting. Kindly help me identify the error.

```
with temp1 as
(select num, 
       id, 
       row_number () over (partition by num order by id) as r
from logs),  
temp2 as
(select (id-r) as rn, num, count(num)  
from temp1
group by rn, num
having count(num)>=3)
select num as ConsecutiveNums
from temp
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
with temp as (select num,
  lag(num,1) over (order by id asc)  as preceding_num,
  lead(num,1) over (order by id asc) as succeeding_num
from logs)
select
  distinct num as ConsecutiveNums
from temp
where num = preceding_num
and num = succeeding_num;
```

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7yUJcuMJPncBBnrExKbzYz/174

> LAG:
> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lag
>
> LEAD:
> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lead

Answer (score 0):

[image: test-case-leetcode]

```
SELECT DISTINCT l1.Num AS ConsecutiveNums
FROM Logs l1,
     Logs l2,
     Logs l3
WHERE l1.Id + 1 = l2.Id
  AND l2.Id + 1 = l3.Id
  AND l1.Num = l2.Num
  AND l2.Num = l3.Num
```